# C: casting to structure with different size

Tags: c, struct, casting, variable-assignment, undefined-behavior

Quick simple question;
Does this

```
typedef struct {int a; int b;} S1;
typedef struct {int a;} S2;
((S2*)(POINTER_TO_AN_S1))->a=1;
```

Always return (and assign) the member a of the structure? Or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: Language tags are important when code is involved (i.e. almost always here on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

In a conforming compiler, if both structure types appear within the complete definition of a union type which is visible where the structure is accessed, and if the target of the pointer happened to be an instance of that union type, behavior would be defined.  Note that the Standard does not require that the compiler have any way of knowing that the target of the pointer is actually an object of that union type--merely that the declaration of the complete union type be visible.

Note, however, that gcc does not abide by the Standard here, unless the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag is used.  Even in cases where the complete union type is visible, and a compiler can see that it is in fact working with objects of the union type, gcc ignores the aliasing.  For example, given:

```
struct s1 {int x;};
struct s2 {int x;};
union u { struct s1 s1; struct s2 s2;};

int read_s1_x(struct s1 *p) { return p->x; }
int read_s2_x(struct s2 *p) { return p->x; }
int write_s1_x(struct s1 *p, int value) { p->x = value; }
int write_s2_x(struct s2 *p, int value) { p->x = value; }

int test(union u *u1, union u *u2)
{
  write_s2_x(&u2->s2, 0);
  if (!read_s1_x(&u1->s1))
    write_s2_x(&u2->s2, 1);
  return read_s1_x(&u1->s1);
}
```

a compiler will decide that it no doesn't need to re-read the value of
u1->s1.x after it writes u2->s2.x, even though the complete union type
is visible and even though a compiler can see that both u1 and u2 are
pointers to objects of the union type.  I'm not quite sure what the
authors of gcc think the address-of operator is supposed to mean when
applied to a union type if the resulting pointer can't even be used to
immediately access an object of that member type.